# save avi files in blender using python script

Tags: python, scripting

I have created an animation using Blender. Does anybody know how I can save .avi file of the rendered animation using a python script?

My second question is that I want to run the animation with different parameters and save the video. Basically, I want to reset the animation and run it again with a new force and save a separate video file. I want to do these automatically instead of manually. Is it possible to do that with scripting?

Comment: Assume by **animation** you mean **image sequence** ?

Comment: Also asking 2 questions at once isn't good, best just ask 2 separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bpy.context.scene.render.filepath` contains the filename that the render will be saved to, you can change this and then use [bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bpy.ops.render.html?highlight=render#bpy.ops.render.render) to render the animation to the specified file.

```
import bpy
bpy.context.active_object.material_slots[0].material = bpy.data.materials['Red']
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = '//red.avi'
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)

bpy.context.active_object.material_slots[0].material = bpy.data.materials['Blue']
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = '//blue.avi'
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
```

The `//` at the beginning of the filename puts the file in the same folder as the blend file.